# How implement 'remember me' in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, session-cookies

How to implement rememeber me  functionality in laravel 5.1? Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Have you try to find or to do something, what kind of application are you trying to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Laravel authentication offers **remember me** functionality out of the box.

In order to use it you need to do 2 things:

- add **remember_token** column in your users table - this is where the token will be stored
- pass **true** as a second parameter of **Auth::attempt()** to enable **remember me** behaviour

If you do this, Laravel will generate a token that will be saved in users table and in a cookie. On subsequent requests, even if session cookie is not available, user will be authenticated automatically as long as remember-me cookie is there.

You can find more details and example in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#remembering-users

Comment: Nice, this is also available in Laravel 4.2 as I look into my project using old version.

Answer (score 2):

laravel can provide a remember me functionality.

you can use simply.

```
public function login(Request $req)
{
    $req->validate([
        'username' => 'required|email|min:8|max:50',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|max:50'
    ]);

    $remember_me = $req->has('remember_me') ? true : false;

    $check = $req->only('username', 'password');
    
    if(Auth::attempt($check, $remember_me))
    {
        return redirect('admin/dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        session()->put('error-msg', "Please enter the valid username and password");
        return redirect('admin/login');
    }
}
```