# Always remember users in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How could I make it so that in my laravel sign in controller, users are always remembered?

I tried making `$remember_me = 1`

but that doesn't seem to work.

Controller:

```
public function postSignin(Request $request, AppMailer $mailer) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);     

    $username = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    $field = filter_var($username,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)? 'email': 'username';      

    Auth::attempt([$field => $username, 'password' => $password], true);


    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'You are now signed in.');
}
```

Start of Home controller:

```
public function getIndex() {
    if (Auth::check()) {

        if (Auth::viaRemember()) {
            dd('test');
        }
```

Edit: I changed the code a bit to explain why the current answer isn't working for me.

Comment: Try with this: `if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}` and to check remembered users:
`if (Auth::viaRemember()) {
    //
}`

Comment: You should check this question's answer [Laravel Remember Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651823/how-implement-remember-me-in-laravel-5-1).

Comment: Ah. That link helps. So     if(!Auth::attempt([$field => $username, 'password' => $password],true))  would do it?

Comment: also how can I test if a user is being remembered or not?

Comment: @FelixMaxime `Auth::viaRemember()`

Comment: You may pass a boolean value as the second argument to the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely, or until they manually logout. Of course, your users table must include the string remember_token column, which will be used to store the "remember me" token. See my code in my 1st comment!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: @FelixMaxime Yes...  your users table must include the string remember_token column..and you should have to put one checkbox in your login form that will define remember me or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass a boolean value as the second argument to the `attempt` method, which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely, or until they manually logout. Of course, your `users` table must include the string `remember_token` column, which will be used to store the "remember me" token.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
     // The user is being remembered...
}
```

> If you are using the built-in `LoginController` that is shipped with
>   Laravel, the proper logic to "remember" users is already implemented
>   by the traits used by the controller.

If you are `"remembering"` users, you may use the `viaRemember` method to determine if the user was authenticated using the "remember me" cookie:

```
if (Auth::viaRemember()) {
    //
}
```

**EDIT :**

Check your `config/session.php` setting:

```
'lifetime' => 10080,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

Just set your `expire_on_close` to `true`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hey Hiren. I tried your answer, however Auth::viaRemember() never works for me. I edited my original post to show my whole login controller. I have an if viaremember condition in my homecontroller that doesn't go off despite putting the remember value to true in auth attempt.

Comment: Have you passed `$remember` in `Auth::attempt` and saved `remember_token`?

Comment: I passed true, not $remember. My entire login function is there to see in my post now

Comment: See your condition: `if(!Auth::attempt([$field => $username, 'password' => $password], true))` You're using `!Auth::attempt` Some mistake was there!

Comment: Also, remove all other logic to resend email, confirm email...just try with login with remember me. It'll work!

Comment: Ok. I removed all that stuff from my controller. I updated my main post to reflect that. It still doesn't work. It logs me in, but viaremember doesn't go off.

Comment: Check in `config/session.php` file: `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie'),  <- Default file

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => true,  <- this was on false`

Comment: I switched  lifetime from 120 to 10080, and expire_on_close to true. Still not working. I also tried switching session_driver to cookie instead of file. Not working either. The remember_token in my database is changing at every login, too.

Comment: I am confused, why should expire_on_close be true? I think, we want the session to NOT expire, so the user stays logged in?